# gnucash cashflow reports - different years side-by-side

Tags: gnucash

Is there a way within the gnucash reporting system to compare cashflow reports from two different years?

I'd like to see something like:

```
|   ACCOUNT     | 2015 | 2014 | DIFFERENCE |
|---------------|------|------|------------|
|Expenses:Taxi  | 500  | 450  | +50        |
|Expenses:Music |  80  |  90  | -10        |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no, gnucash will not run multiple years and compare them in a single window.

That being said, there are a couple of options to meet your needs:

1. Run each report (per year) independently, then copy them to a spreadsheet and do any comparisons you need to there.  Most reports are intentionally 'spreadsheet friendly' for exactly this purpose.  You can play with the options to include only the rows you need in your result.
2. Gnucash reports are customizable.  Using Scheme and Guile you can write pretty much anything you want into a custom report.  If you must have the time and desire to try this route, follow the directions **[here](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Custom_Reports)** and then share your results for the betterment of the community.